# jQuery: Update, by class, span tags with datepicker input value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

How can I update just the  tags / class="able", with the datepicker value thats
stored in the `<input id="datepicker">` field?

Steps:

1. Click the "datepicker" input field; Date calendar opens.
2. Select your date; "datepicker" input field populated with selected date.
3. Click "Load" Button.
4. `<span>` tags with `class="able"` values are now equal to "datepicker" input field value.

#### HTML

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<title>jQuery Pass Value Input to SPAN2</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="ui/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
<script src="ui/jquery.ui.datepicker.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div>
<p>Date: <input id="datepicker" type="text"></p>
<br>
<input type="Button" id="button1" Value="LOAD">
</div>

<span id="result1" class="able"> </span>
<span id="result2" class="able"> </span>
<span id="result3" class="able"> </span>

<span id="result4" class="baker"> </span>
<span id="result5" class="baker"> </span>

<span id="result6" class="charlie"> </span>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: MANY THANKS SKS, Gopal Nair and redmoon7777!; 

Thank You for the prompt responses and clear, concise explanations. 

The demo and documentation was an added bonus. 

This is just what I was looking for. 

Tak

Answer (score 2):

You need to bind an onclick event to the load button and inside the onclick function you need to set the span text like below,

```
 $('#button1').click (function () {
      $('span.able').text($('#datepicker').val());
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/3MK7y/)**

Answer (score 0):

Here is the JQuery Code to do this:

```
$("span.able").text($("#datepicker").text());
```

What the above code does is, to select all the span tags, with class = "able". It then sets its internal text to the value present in your text box with ID = datepicker.

Here is the documentation for text() function:
http://api.jquery.com/text/

Answer (score 0):

```
$("Load-button-selector").click( function(){
    $("span.able").html( $("datepicker-filed-selector").val() );
});
```

Comment: val works on input elements and not tags like span/div. you should use text/html to set the innerHTML of those elements

Comment: `.live` is deprecated. Additionally, what benefit does it provide here over simply using `.click` or `.on("click")`?

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker you are right, I was just making sure that even if the button is created afterwards the script would still be valid